# Managing JS objects while preserving references

Tags: javascript, angular.js

**Scenario**

I have `foo`:

```
{
    name: 'Mr. Foo',
    value: 4
}
```

I receive `bar` from the server:

```
{
    name: 'Mrs. Bar',
    description: 'Wife of Mr. Bar'
}
```

I wish to update `foo` to be identical to `bar` (containing only the same properties and values in bar, and nothing more), but I need every reference to now know about these new values. This means doing `foo = bar` won't work because anything that had a reference to `foo` still has reference to `foo`'s original values and will keep just looking at those.

**Possible Solution**

I have been using [`angular.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) in the cases that I know for a fact the properties will always be the same, but if I do that in this scenario, `foo` will wind up with `name`, `value`, and `description` properties, when I need only `name` and `description`.

I came up with the following "replacement" function as a part of a utility service designed to solve this problem, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this (something that perhaps looks less prone to obscure bugs than this does).

```
replaceObj: function (obj, updates) {
    if (obj && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
        // Extend original object
        angular.extend(obj, updates);

        // Get object keys
        var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
        var updatesKeys = Object.keys(updates);

        // Delete original object properties that are not included in the updates object
        objKeys.forEach(function(objKey) {
            if (updatesKeys.indexOf(objKey) === -1)
                delete obj[objKey];
        });
    } else {
        console.error('utility.replaceObj called without valid parameters.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just delete all the properties from the original object, then use `Object.assign()`?

Comment: My understanding was that `Object.assign()` only copies references to any non-primitive properties... As I'm typing this, I'm thinking that might actually be sufficient for my use case. I'm not creating any additional references to the `bar` object, so it should be safe to "transfer" ownership of any existing non-primitive properties to `foo`. Thanks for that suggestion. If you'd like an easy +15 rep, you can add an answer.

Comment: Isn't that the same as `angular.extend()`? The documentation says **Extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable properties from the src object(s) to dst.**

Comment: And `Object.assign` doc says: **The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.**

Comment: Yes it is, and you're right. I think I had been working through other issues when I made this change, fixed those issues, and then left this as it was. That's why I'm here--I saw it again today and thought "Why was I doing it this way..?" and couldn't think of a reason. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking each property in the result to see whether it was in the source object, simply delete all of the properties in the destination object and then use `angular.extend` or `Object.assign` to copy from the source.

```
function replaceObj(target, source) {
    Object.keys(target).forEach(function(key) {
        delete target[key];
    });
    Object.assign(target, source);
}
```

Also, if you do want to check whether a property is in an object, using `updates.kasOwnProperty(objKey)` is more straightforward than making a separate array of keys and using `indexOf`.